# (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

Tags: python, mysql, django, jupyter

I am on mac with homebrew mysql, making a django app. I also use jupyter. I don't know which of these things is the root cause of the issue.

I used to get this error message coming up every now and again, and I know how to fix it: just type `brew services restart mysql` and wait a bit.

The problem is that it's now happening with increasing frequency, several times an hour. Is there a known fix for this, when working on a local machine?

I thought, since I'm `ctrl-c` ing programs frequently, that might be exhausting the connection pool so I increased the connection pool size using `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 5000;`, but that has not helped.

Comment: Did you verify that mysql is actually running, for example by running `ps aux | grep mysqld` in a terminal?

Comment: @kristaps Yes, mysql is running. Often when this happens, some thing I am running will start showing the error but others will not.

Comment: Any errors in the server logs from around the time of failed connections?

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion - I would give Docker a shot *(since you keep getting these interruptions)*.

Create a new container which will run your MySQL server exposing a port to the DB server then connect to that from your mac.

Here's a good resource to get you started - https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/#-via-docker-stack-deploy-or-docker-compose

Alternatively, if you don't have to use MySQL you could try using PostgreSQL. Here's a good article for that one - https://medium.com/agatha-codes/painless-postgresql-django-d4f03364989 . Many django projects are using that in production as it has a lot more features to offer.

Comment: This is already a large service running in production, switching database  is not an option. I may try Docker locally if nothing else works though.

Comment: Why the downvote? My suggestion was for your local environment obviously since you didn't mention anywhere that it's a production server.

Have you checked that your settings.py file is correct for your local environment (e.g. you're not trying to connect to your production server from your computer)?